# using ng-repeat in html to display several images in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, controller

I have this HTML code:

```
                   <li data-thumb="images/ss.jpg">
                       <img src="images/ss.jpg"/>
                   </li>
                    <li data-thumb="images/ss1.jpg">
                        <img src="images/ss1.jpg"/>
                    </li>
                    <li data-thumb="images/ss2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/ss2.jpg"/>
                    </li>
                    <li data-thumb="images/ss3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/ss3.jpg"/>
                    </li>
```

And I wish to use my `angularJS` controller in order to create something like this in my HTML instead:

```
                    <li data-thumb="{{image[i].src[i]}}" ng-repeat="image in images">
                        <img ng-src="{{image[i].src]i]}}"/>
                    </li>
```

(I know the above code doesn't work, that is why I am asking...)

So essentially I will have the same output as before (4 different images).
My "ListingCtrl" controller so far has this:

```
$scope.images = [{
        src1: 'images/ss.jpg',
        src2: 'images/ss1.jpg',
        src3: 'images/ss2.jpg',
        src4: 'images/ss3.jpg',
    }];
```

I will appreciate any help in making me accomplish this!
In the future I want to parse a JSON file there and get the images from that instead... But I guess this should be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you have an array of objects. So to print the image list do this:

```
<li data-thumb="{{ images[$index][key] }}" ng-repeat="(key, image) in images track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{ images[$index][key] }}"/>
</li>
```

or a simpler version

```
<li data-thumb="{{ image }}" ng-repeat="(key, image) in images track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{ image }}"/>
</li>
```

If you need to get the index of the image inside the array just print out or use the **$index** variable like so:

```
{{ $index }}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this::

```
<li data-thumb="{{ images[$index][key] }}" ng-repeat="(key, image) in images track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{ images[$index][key] }}"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :( the images are "displayed" but are empty (i can't actually see them)

Comment: then there must be no images at that url.

Comment: How could this be if beforehand it showed the images? (When i just used the normal <img src="images/ss.jpg"/>    )

Answer (score 1):

Your images array just contains one object. If this is the data stucture, then iterate over the first element of your array in a key value fashion:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in images>"
    <img ng-src="{{v}}"/>
</div>
```

Ideally, your images variable should either be an array or an object. The current data structure doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right, I meant for it to be an array of 4 images (4 entries) and not an array of a 4-image-object.
I changed the controller code to:
$scope.images = {
            src1: 'images/ss.jpg',
            src2: 'images/ss1.jpg',
            src3: 'images/ss2.jpg',
            src4: 'images/ss3.jpg',
        };

Any sense now?

Comment: Yes, now just replace 'images[0]' by 'images' in my answer.

Comment: Sadly it still does not work.. It even "messed up" my angular for other things apparently..Can you provide with the full 2 lines of code that you meant? Because you only posted part of the lines.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!